# How to convert webcam blob url to base64 string

Tags: flutter, dart

I am trying to implement a capture image functionality on the website using Flutter/dart and store it in the database in base64 format. I have successfully implemented the capture image functionality using the camera package(^0.9.4+21) but I am facing an issue while converting it in the base64 because the camera web gives a blob URL (blob:http://url:/).

Is there any way I can convert blob URL to base 64 string?

Or Is there any other better way to handle image on website?

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I'm having a similar problem with fetching recorded audio from the webcam.

Comment: No. I didn't get any solution. I change the functionality to upload the image